# Outlook addin: change inline response text

Tags: outlook-addin

With outlook VSTO addin I would like to change an email text when the user replies to an email. I manage to change the text when the response is not inline (i.e. when clicking "Reply" you also click "Pop out"). This is done by modifying `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Text`.

However, when using inline response (without clicking "Pop out") modifying the above member throws an exception. I noticed that the reason is that in inline response the `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor` is protected (read only). so I use `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Unprotect` method for allowing modifications. after this, changing the text doesn't throw an exception any more but also doesn't have any effect - the text stays the same.

Same behavior when trying to modify `Range.Text` using OutlookSpy.

Why changing `Range.Text` doesn't have any effect for inline response?

Answer (score 0):

For inline response, you should not be using `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor`, but `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` - what is the difference between the two - isn't it the same Document object? also, if I'm working  with some MailItem, can I know that its type is Inline Response? (otherwise, if my MailItem is some new email, `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` does not correspond to the MailItem I'm working with)

Comment: That depends on where your MailItem comes from. Is it Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse?

Comment: Plus there is no inspector for an inline reply.

Comment: I'm listening on ItemSend event. inside ItemSend callback I have a MailItem. can I know whether this is inline response or not? if it's not inline response but a regular email then `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` will give me Document object for some inline response email that happened to be active at the same time my regular email was sent.

Comment: If you are using Application.ItemSend event, you will be better off working with the MailItem.HTMLBody property.